# How to read XML file and display it in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to display an XML file in a `UITableView`.  Also, if I click on one of the `tableRow`, it should open in new view.

Comment: How are you going to display it? One line per row (all lines) or one collapsed node per row (tapping it would uncollapse it? or would tapping it pop another table view with its child-nodes)? Are you thinking of doing any indentation? ... I think that you need to give us some more information to be able to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's two fairly big tasks for a two-sentence question. One approach to reading an XML file would be to use NSXMLParser. Apple has a [good document describing how to use it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html). Start with that and post more questions here if you get stuck. You'll usually find that more specific questions get more specific answers.

**Oh.** I just noticed the question is six months old. I guess that proves my point.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps and ask more specific questions if you get stuck:

1. Download the Data using NSURLConnection
2. Use NSXMLParser to parse the data and store it in a collection (NSArray is probably what you want).
3. Use UITableView's Delegate and datasource methods to create cells and respond to cell selections.

Comment: I have XML data example , this format How to arrange and store into Array .  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Choyawo version="1.0">
<language>ja</language>
<pubDate>Mon, 13 Aug 2012 21:01:09 JST</pubDate>
<item>
<location>
<type>IATA</type>
<query>HND, Tokyo Haneda International, Japan</query>
</location>
<currentCondition>
<observation_time>10:34 AM</observation_time>
<temp_C>29</temp_C>
<temp_F>84</temp_F>
<weatherCode>116</weatherCode>
<weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[www.tokyo-airport-bldg.co.jp/images/api/weather/sunny_cloudy.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
<weatherDesc><![CDATA[Partly Cloudy]]>